# C simple program

Tags: c

I'm learning starting to learn C, so I tried to make a simple program with what I know. The program SHOULD ask for a letter, ask if you want the position of a letter in the alphabet(if so it displays "x is the y letter in the alphabet" with the suffix) and then it asks if you want the letter in binary and puts it in binary. But for some reason it doesn't work. I tried "manual debugging"(using puts() to see what doesn't work) and the class "getNumber" works but the value changes when it goes to the main class.

```
 a returns "2686719" instead of "a is the 1st letter in the alphabet" and b returns "2b is the 2z\<<y in the alphabet".
```

This is the code, what did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//011
int main(){
    int x = 2;
    char letter;
    puts("Write a letter");
    char temp2;
    scanf("%c", &temp2);
    int number;
    letter = temp2;
    puts("get alphabet position? y/n ");
    char temp[2];
    scanf("%s", temp);
    char answer = temp[0];
    int tempNumber2 = getNumber(letter);
    if(answer == 'y'){
        char suffix[3];
        int number = tempNumber2;
        printf("%d", number);
        if (number == 1){
            x = 1;
            suffix[0] = "s";
            suffix[1] = "t";
        }else if (number < 27){
            suffix[0] = "t";
            suffix[1] = "h";
            x = 1;
        }
        if (x == 1){
            printf("%c is the %d", letter, number);
            printf("%s in the alphabet\n", suffix);
        }}else if (answer == 'n'){
        x = 1;
        }else if (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n'){
            puts("ERROR, invalid letter");
            x = 3;
    };
    if(x != 3){
        puts("Convert to binary?");
    }
    return 0;
}
int getNumber(letter){
    char tempLetter = letter;
    int tempNumber = -1;
    char alphabet[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 27){
        i++;
        if(tempLetter == alphabet[i]){
            tempNumber = i;
            tempNumber++;
            printf("%d \n", tempNumber);
            return tempNumber;
        }
    };
}
```

By the way, I haven't gotten to the binary part hence why it's empty.

Comment: Buffer overrun. You increment i before looking up the letter in the array, so the loop in getNumber starts looking at alphabet[1].

Comment: Also, I'm not certain on it but it may be undefined behaviour, or at least implementation dependant whether defining a function you after you use it actually does something normal.

Comment: Next time use "function" where you now are using "class" (`class` is nothing, in this C context, but it *does* have a definite meaning it the closely related C++). In addition to the above, you forget to zero-terminate the `suffix` string. The number appears in front of your output because you `printf` it in the `getNumber` function. (As said above, the *wrong* number.)

Comment: `suffix[0] = "s";` --> `suffix[0] = 's';`

Comment: I did what user1937198, user3121023 and BLUEPIXY said and now it worked, thanks. I'll come back again once I finish the binary part and don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Or change `suffix[0] = "t"; suffix[1] = "h";` to `strcpy(suffix, "th");`. (Or declare `char * suffix;` then assign `suffix = "th";` is probably simplest)

Comment: `char temp[2]; scanf("%s", temp);` -- This is dangerous. If the user inputs more than one letter (say, "yes" rather than "y"), this will overflow `temp`. You used `scanf("%c", ...)` for the previous 1-character input; why use `"%s"` here?

Answer (score 3):

As everyone stated in the comments your problem is that suffix's last char is not set to '\0'.

Moreover, you could `getNumber` in a much simpler way:

```
int getNumber(char letter) {
    return (int)(letter - 'a') + 1;
}
```

Btw, you can make your code look a little better (didn't change it too much):

```
int main() {
    char letter;
    char answer;

    puts("Write a letter");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    getchar(); // read \n
    puts("get alphabet position? y/n ");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    getchar(); // read \n
    if (answer == 'n') {
        return 0;
    }
    if (answer != 'y') {
        puts("ERROR, invalid letter");
        return 1;
    }

    int number = getNumber(letter);
    char suffix[3];
    suffix[2] = 0;

    if (number == 1) {
        suffix[0] = 's';
        suffix[1] = 't';
    } else if (number == 2) {
        suffix[0] = 'n';
        suffix[1] = 'd';
    } else if (number == 3) {
        suffix[0] = 'r';
        suffix[1] = 'd';
    } else {
        suffix[0] = 't';
        suffix[1] = 'h';
    }
    printf("%c is the %d%s letter in the alphabet\n", letter, number, suffix);

    puts("Convert to binary?");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor note: actually, the OP's method of indexing a character is independent of the encoding used. Your code assumes ASCII, where the original code would work with *any* encoding - even one as exotic as EBDIC. (Mind you, I'd probably do the same. A good alternative is `strchr`.)

Comment: It doesn't assume ascii, it just assumes that the abc is consecutive (which i think is true for every encoding out there).

Comment: "Assume `abc` is consecutive" -- correct (and thanks for pointing that out). "True for every encoding" - [false](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

Comment: LOL. Nice example. :)
well, it's a good thing we don't program in the 50's - 60's. :)

Comment: Why the cast in `(int)(letter - 'a')`?  Why not simply `return letter - 'a' + 1;`?

Comment: You're right, it's not mandatory, just reads better in my opinion.